# Pthread: when Dynamic mutex initialization must be used

Tags: c, initialization, pthreads

As everyone knows, there are two ways how to init pthread mutex (C language)

1. Static initialization:

   ```
   pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
   ```
2. Dynamic initialization:

   ```
   pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
   pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
   pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP); 
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
   ```

var 1 - I used it many times.

var 2 - the reason I posted this question:
Will really appreciate if someone could provide me with some real example(s) when dynamic initialization of pthread mutex must be used.

Thanks!

Comment: Applied [code] tags

Answer (score 2):

You always need the `pthread_*_init()` functions if the default attributes won't do/are not suitable.

[An example can be found at the bottom of this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_destroy.html).

Comment: Yes. Note that OP's example of `PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` is non portable (that's explicitly what the NP stands for).